# Brush tool that only moves points in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pen-tool, selections

Is there a tool similar to the warp tool but only to move points without smoothing lines? The nearest example would be the soft vertex selection tool found in 3D programs.

A shape is modified within the brush area without smoothing lines just repositioning the affected points thus straight lines remain being straight.

Is there a tool or a plugin for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not that I'm aware of.

You can alter the **options** of the Warp Tool by double-clicking it in the Tool Bar. I always uncheck Detail and Simplify to make the tool more controllable.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Scott, unchecking detail and simplify make it work exactly as I needed.